# Continuity and weak differentiability with continuous weak derivative implies strong continuous differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, weak-derivatives

Let $u: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. If $u$ is strongly differentiable (i.e. differentiable in the classic sense) with strong derivative $u'$, then $u$ is also weakly differentiable and every weak derivative equals $u'$ almost everywhere.

Now, assume $u$ is continuous and has a continuous weak derivative: can we conclude that $u$ is continuously differentiable in the strong (i.e. usual) sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The weak derivative is unique, so there are no "several derivatives" (notice that we don't work with *functions*, but rather with *class of functions*).
- For your second question, the answer is yes. This is a simple consequence of the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements). Moreover, instead of saying that *"there is a continuous weak derivative"*, we rather say that *"there is a continuous representative of the derivative"*.